# Parsing a JSON with []

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

I am having trouble accessing parts of a json that looks like this. The thing I am looking to get is precip type.

```
{
        "latitude": 42.3601,
        "daily": {
          "data": [
            {
              "time": 255589200,
              "icon": "snow",
              "sunriseTime": 255613996,
              "sunsetTime": 255650764,
              "moonPhase": 0.97,
              "precipIntensity": 0.0354,
              "precipIntensityMax": 0.1731,
              "precipIntensityMaxTime": 255657600,
              "precipProbability": 1,
              "precipAccumulation": 7.337,
              "precipType": "snow",
              "temperatureHigh": 31.84,
            }
          ]
        },
        "offset": -5
      }
```

So far I have tried

`response['daily']['data']['precipType']`

and also this (I didn't expect this to work though, it was just a try)

`response['daily']['data.precipType']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since data is an array you need to access the items inside the array by the index.

```
puts response["daily"]["data"][0]["precipType"]
```

For the first element in the array.

Or loop over all items in the array like so

```
response["daily"]["data"].each do |item|
  puts item["precipType"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.